# Are there any open-source congnative planing frameworks for robotics?

Tags: mobile-robot, algorithm, planning

I have seen a lot of academic papers, but no framework that I can download and use. There are even projects, such as OpenCog, which might be usable in a few years.

I would like to know of the existence of any open-source goal/cognitive/planning frameworks now.

There is a lot of software for motion planning, but I would like a way to determine where the robot wants to do before planning how to get there.

Comment: Take a look at OMPL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> KnowRob is a knowledge processing system that combines knowledge representation and reasoning methods with techniques for acquiring knowledge and for grounding the knowledge in a physical system and can serve as a common semantic framework for integrating information from different sources. KnowRob combines static encyclopedic knowledge, common-sense knowledge, task descriptions, environment models, object information and information about observed actions that has been acquired from various sources (manually axiomatized, derived from observations, or imported from the web). It supports different deterministic and probabilistic reasoning mechanisms, clustering, classification and segmentation methods, and includes query interfaces as well as visualization tools.

http://www.knowrob.org/

Comment: Thank you. I will need to look at the documentation when I'm awake. It does look like it will do what I would like.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at ROS. They have motion planning packages. Sorry I can't provide more detail at this time, but I know ROS packages exist... and they are open source. This is a good question for their forum if you don't get a better answer here.

Comment: I understand that there is a motion planning package in ROS. There are many motion planning packages. I want something that will help a robot choose among a number of goals or a number of ways to implement a goal.

Answer (score 0):

There is a framework for motion planning in ROS, it is called MoveIt!
http://moveit.ros.org/

The main limitation of it, is that it falls apart, but if you get the single configuration in which it works it can do the job.

Otherwise you will have to find your way within all the other packages developed in ROS or YARP (http://www.yarp.it/) that do a similar job.

I am not aware of a state-of-the-art integrated solution yet